# Smarty Template - foreach only display 2 results at a time

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

Good morning / afternoon,

I am looking for help with regards to the following:

```
{foreach key=num item=customfield from=$customfields}
<div class="control-group" style="margin-bottom:0px">
    <label class="control-label" for="customfield{$customfield.id}">{$customfield.name}</label>
    <div class="controls" style="margin-left:145px;">
    {$customfield.input} {$customfield.description}
    </div>
</div>
{/foreach}
```

My smarty template has a login page that is setup with a 2 column registration page, as in:

col1 has name, last name, email etc.
col2 has address, address 2, etc.

These all align to have col1 on the left and col2 on the right within a table.

Now using the above code, the foreach code, it will only style into a 1 column table, not 2.

How would i go about making it display 2 results at a time and display them within the table.

I would like to thanks everyone for helping in advance.

edit 2.

```
{foreach key=num item=customfield from=$customfields}
{if $customfields@interation is even by 2}
<tr><td>{$customfield.name}{$customfield.input}{$customfield.description}</td>
{else} <td><td>{$customfield.name}{$customfield.input}{$customfield.description}</td>
</tr>{/if}{/foreach}
```

What needs changing?

edit 3.

Problem solved with the following code.

```
{foreach from=$customfields item=customfield name=ODDEVEN }
<tr><td style="border-left:0px;">
{if $smarty.foreach.ODDEVEN.index % 2}
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="customfield{$customfield.id}" style="width:125px;">{$customfield.name}</label>
    <div class="controls" style="margin-left:145px;">
    {$customfield.input} {$customfield.description}
    </div>
</div>
{else}</td>
<td><div class="control-group" style="margin-bottom:0px">
    <label class="control-label" for="customfield{$customfield.id}" style="width:125px;">{$customfield.name}</label>
    <div class="controls" style="margin-left:145px;">
    <div class="fixinput span4">{$customfield.input}</div> {$customfield.description}
    </div>
</div>
</td></tr>
{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: where is table in your code? use key=num, num variable with % 2, to find odd even. and add all odd number to col1 and rest in col2

Comment: It would be styled like this:    {foreach blah blah}<tr><td>content1</td><td>content2</td></tr>{/foreach}